# How to log all unhandled exceptions in the Cocoa application and save the application from crashing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Nobody likes an app crash and so I. I need to log all the errors that may cause a crash so that later on I can push them on the server in order make the application more robust.

Q1. Is it possible to handle an unhandled exception. Something like global exception handling?

Q2. If the app crashes then is it possible to at least log the error with line number and file name in order identify the error?

**My research**

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&onUncaughtException);

   ///raising error on purpose in order to check
   [NSException raise:@"Invalid foo value" format:@"foo of %d is invalid", 1];
}

void onUncaughtException(NSException *exception)
{
    NSArray *stack = [exception callStackReturnAddresses];
    NSLog(@"Stack trace: %@", stack);
}
```

This is not working. When I am raising the exception then the application is crashing but the exception is not getting logged.

Many thanks for your attention and for any help that you can offer.

Comment: "more robust"?  If something is raising an exception then the app is likely not working and the user will simply think the app is broken.  This has the same effect as just crashing except you don't get crash reports for free.

Comment: @trojanfoe I have raised an exception on purpose in order to check if I can save the application from crashing or if I can log the exception that is not handled. Please let me know if I have to mention this in the question?

Comment: @trojanfoe crash reports are not free?? can not we log the crash and send it when the app run next time??

Comment: I guess it depends if the app is released via the app store or not.  If so, don't Apple provide crash reports for Mac Apps?

Comment: Its not a app store app :( However it is signed by developer id

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your code (with the obvious corrections to the method signature and function name) logs the stack prior to terminating the app.

Comment: @RobNapier I apologies. the selector function name was not correct. I have updated the code. Please have a look

Comment: Crash handling is extremely complicated and it is very easy to deadlock the program so that it busy-waits the CPU if you do it incorrectly (true story; very embarrassing and frustrating). You will want an established tool like https://www.plcrashreporter.org.

Comment: Exceptions in Objective-C are designed to be used for un-recoverable programming errors. There is little to no cleanup for exceptions caught across stack frames so the app will have corruption. Since a catastrophic event has occurred there is no guarantee that continued execution is possible and may even cause data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Use an existing free and robust solution like [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) . It's fantastic and easy to use!